# Testing Rspec after_action that changes counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have my controller which I'm trying to test.

```
class ShortLinksController < ApplicationController
  after_action :increment_view_count, only: :redirect_to_original_url

  def redirect_to_original_url
    link = ShortLink.find(params[:short_url])

    redirect_to "http://#{link.original_url}"
  end

  private

  def increment_view_count
    ShortLink.increment_counter(:view_count, params[:short_url])
  end

end
```

This is the route for redirect_to_original_url:

```
get 's/:short_url', to: 'short_links#redirect_to_original_url', as: 'redirect_to_original_url'
```

And my Rspec tests:

```
describe "#redirect_to_original_url" do
  let(:short_link) {ShortLink.create(original_url: 'www.google.com')}

  subject {get :redirect_to_original_url, params: {short_url: short_link.id}}

  it 'should increment the count by 1 original url is visited' do
    expect {subject}.to change{ short_link.view_count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

For some reason I get the following error when I run my tests:

```
expected `short_link.view_count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

My logic works as I can see it increments that individual link view_count by 1, but not my test.

Comment: Is the `after_action` of `increment_view_count` being called in your test? You'd know this by putting a debugger or `puts` inside that function.

Comment: @JakeWorth Yes it is being called

Comment: Nice! What is the count before and after the subject is invoked in the test? You could figure this out by replacing the ‘expect’ with just printing the count, calling the action, then printing the count again.

Comment: It is still 0. That's why it's weird. I thought maybe I need to do a reload, but that didnt' work.

Comment: Try `change{ short_link.reload.view_count }`

Comment: Great, so `increment_view_count` is being called in the test, but the count is not incrementing even after reloading. Could you share `ShortLink.increment_counter`?

Comment: @Vasilisa Putting the reload before short_link, fixed the issue. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @Anthony you're welcome! If you don't mind I'll convert my comment to answer, to not leave the question unanswered

Answer (score 2):

Check the default value of view_count when you create a object for ShortLink model using,

```
let(:short_link) {ShortLink.create(original_url: 'www.google.com')}
//Creating object

it 'should have value 0 when shortlink object is created' do
expect(short_link.view_count).to eq(0)
end
```

If this example fails then create object with default value for view_count as,

```
let(:short_link) {ShortLink.create(original_url: 'www.gmail.com',view_count: 0)}
```

Meanwhile as [Jake Worth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112512/jake-worth) said your rspec test is not calling,

```
after_action :increment_view_count, only: :redirect_to_original_url
```

in your controller(check this by calling increment_view_count function from your redirect_to_original_url function and run your tests).

Answer (score 0):

Since you created `short_link` variable you need to reload it to check that value was changed. Unless reloading it stores previous value.

```
expect { subject }.to change{ short_link.reload.view_count }.by(1)
```